# Optimization for jsPDF, downloading pdf using jspdf and html2canvas takes 5 seconds or more

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

How can I optimize the jspdf? so that I can generate the pdf and download it within a second.

here is the snippet of the code I'm using.

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

export const printDocument = (document: HTMLElement | null, fileName: string) => {
  if (!document) {
    return
  }

  html2canvas(document, { scale: 1, useCORS: true }).then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
    const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4', true)
    const pdfw = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth()
    const pdfh = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight()
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, pdfw - 20, pdfh - 5)
    pdf.save(fileName)
  })
}
```

I tried removing the scaling to remove the heavy rendering and lower the file size, but it has no effect. I'm using react and useRef for my HTMLDivElement.

Comment: Don’t use `data:` URIs - ugh.